# Complete in-progress merge with the --no-verify option

Tags: magit

Often when I'm merge the upstream branch into my branch I'll need to fix up some merge conflicts. At that point I have an in-progress merge. When I fix the conflict and hit `m` to complete the merge there is no `--no-verify` option available. The only options are `merge` and `abort`.

`--no-verify` would be useful because often the upstream code has changes that will fail my pre-commit hooks (style linters, etc).

Is there a way to add `--no-verify` when completing an in-progress merge?

Answer (score 1):

In the in-progress state I can just use the regular `c` commit command, and select `no-verify` there.